# linux sort -n uniq -c

Tags: linux, awk, uniq

I have a text file which contains about 50MB of text:

```
valA
valB
valC
valZ
valB
```

Whats the quickest way to:

1. cat the file
2. Display the unique appearences

Comment: You don't need to cat the file. You can just do uniq file.txt > uniq.txt which will probably be fastest instead of stdout.

Comment: seems like 'cat text.txt | uniq -c | sort -n ' may be the answer

Comment: @Clustermagnet: You'd want to do `sort` first, then call `uniq`. Useless use of cat. Try: `< text.txt sort -n | uniq -c`

Comment: @Clustermagnet: UUOC Award?  It isn't clear that counts are wanted or needed, so `sort -u text.txt`?  If counts are wanted, then `sort text.txt | uniq -c` works, optionally followed by `sort -n` to put the lines into frequency order.

Comment: @squiguy: the file must be sorted before `uniq` works sanely.  The input clearly isn't sorted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler His question was just a little unclear, I didn't see the sort part at first.

Comment: What are 'the unique appearances'?  One instance of each word that appears?  Or one instance (the only instance) of each word that appears only once?  Please clarify by editing the question. (Incidentally, it's awfully tempting to say that the fastest way to `cat` the file is to use `cat file`.)

Comment: Why must it be so fast? I could post my counting hashtable here, but I don't like the need for speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '!array[$0]++' file.txt
```

Results:

```
valA
valB
valC
valZ
```

---

Food for thought:

```
sort -u file.txt

valA
valB
valC
valZ

< file.txt sort | uniq

valA
valB
valC
valZ

< file.txt sort | uniq -u                 # only print unique lines

valA
valC
valZ

< file.txt sort | uniq -d                 # only print duplicate lines

valB
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort text.txt | uniq -c | grep "^\s*1 "`

- you have to sort before uniq
- grep those ones of count=1

notice valB is not unique here.

**Edit**

How could I miss there is -u for uniq: `uniq -u` yet use this silly way:)